# How to avoid duplicate IMEI NO of phone in Android Application?

Tags: java, android

I wanna avoid same request of multiple user from same device in my android application. For that case, I wanna avoid duplicate IMEI NO of phone that how one user can't  request an event from multiple user ID using same device.

How can i do this?

How can drop a pin on specific location?

If one user registered on my application, then drop a pin on google map that can I specify the user's in future to search as another users nearby. How can I do this on android application development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference - https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-retrieve-an-unique-id-to-identify-android-devices-6f99fd5369eb

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.Context;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.
                TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
/*
 * getDeviceId() returns the unique device ID.
 * For example,the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones.
*/
String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

You will need to request for permission - android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE 
Also, verify if this requires runtime permission on M and above!